# Fourier Series in Numpy. Question about Previous Answer

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to replicate an answer given in a previous thread:
[How to calculate a Fourier series in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258106/how-to-calculate-a-fourier-series-in-numpy)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

def func(x):
    if x >= 1.0 or x <= -1.0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (abs(x) - 1.0)
a = 1.0
b = -1.0
N = 128.
time = np.linspace( a, b, N )
y = (np.fromiter(itertools.imap(func, time), 
                  dtype=time.dtype, count=time.shape[0]))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(time,y) 
period = 2.
def cn(n):
    c = y*np.exp(-1j*2*n*np.pi*time/period)
    return c.sum()/c.size
def f(x, Nh):
    f = np.array([2*cn(i)*np.exp(1j*2*i*np.pi*x/period) for i in range(1,Nh+1)])
    return f.sum()
y2 = np.array([f(t,10).real for t in time])
ax.plot(time, y2)
plt.show()
```

I'm getting a solution that's close to the right answer, but shifted. I wasn't sure what I am doing wrong.
[image: shifted fourier series]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to be related to your Riemann sum [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods) (right/middle/left) - indicated by [regularfry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843085/fourier-series-in-numpy-question-about-previous-answer/5843249#5843249).  Using the middle method gives:

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

def func(x):
    if x >= 1.0 or x <= -1.0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (abs(x) - 1.0)

a = 1.0
b = -1.0
N = 128.
time = np.linspace( a, b, N )
y = (np.fromiter(itertools.imap(func, time), 
                  dtype=time.dtype, count=time.shape[0]))

period = 2.
def cn(n):
    c = y*np.exp(-1j*2*n*np.pi*time/period)
    return c.sum()/c.size
def f(x, Nh):
    rng = np.arange(.5, Nh+.5)
    f = np.array([2*cn(i)*np.exp(1j*2*i*np.pi*x/period) for i in rng])
    return f.sum()

y2 = np.array([f(t,10).real for t in time])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(time, y)
ax.plot(time, y2)
plt.show()
```

As noted by Sven in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838994/fourier-series-from-discrete-fourier-transform/5844388#5844388) your use of list comprehensions (and `imap`) instead of arrays and [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) is quite inefficient (should you run into performance issues)

Comment: Good to know! I had jumped into list comprehensions because y = dft.real * np.cos(xn) + dft.imag * np.sin(xn) doesn't work since dft is a list. I wasn't sure how to vectorize it.

Comment: also, the reason I used the imap was because when I tried y = func(time) it gave me the following erorr: 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'

Comment: @svaha Yes, `func`, `cn`, and `f` all need to be vectorized to get the speedup numpy offers.  `func`, written for numpy would look something like this: `def func(x):; x=np.abs(x)-1; x[x>=1]==0; x[x<=-1]==0; return x`

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your DC term has got lost somewhere. I can't check for myself right now, but are you sure the 1 in range(1, Nh+1) in f() is correct?

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized version of your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from optparse import OptionParser

def func(x):
    return np.where(np.abs(x) >= 1, 0., np.abs(x) - 1.0)

def cn(x, y, n, period):
    c = y * np.exp(-1j * 2. * np.pi * n * x / period)
    return c.sum()/c.size

def f(x, y, Nh, period):
    rng = np.arange(.5, Nh+.5)
    coeffs = np.array([cn(x,y,i,period) for i in rng])
    f = np.array([2. * coeffs[i] * np.exp(1j*2*i*np.pi*x/period) for i in rng])
    return f.sum(axis=0)

if __name__=='__main__':

    Version = '0.1'
    usage = "usage: %prog [options]"

    parser = OptionParser(usage = usage,version="%prog "+Version)
    parser.add_option("-a", dest='a', type='float', default=1., help="initial time")
    parser.add_option("-b", dest='b', type='float', default=-1., help="end time")
    parser.add_option("-N", "--Nt", dest='N', type='int', default=128, help="number of time steps")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--period", dest='period', type='float', default=2., help="period [time span]")
    parser.add_option("--Nh", dest='Nh', type='int', default=10, help="number of fourier series terms")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    for key,value in options.__dict__.iteritems():
        exec key + ' = ' + repr(value)

    time = np.linspace( a, b, N )
    y = func(time)
    period = np.abs(a-b)

    y2 = f(time,y,Nh,period).real

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(time, y)
    ax.plot(time, y2)
    plt.show()
```

Given that the code has been saved with the name "fourier_series.py", you could try:

python fourier_series.py -N 512 --Nh 128

in a normal terminal or:

%run fourier_series.py -N 512 --Nh 128

in the ipython console